# Integral with function involving decimal expansion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For almost ever $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the decimal expansion $x = a_{0}.a_{1}a_{2}\cdots$ is unique. Let $A_{n}(x) = 1$ if the corresponding $a_{n}$ for $x$ is even and $A_{n}(x) = -1$ if $a_{n}$ is odd. If $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$, why is the following true:
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)A_{n}(x)\, dx = 0 $$